# How to install Cisco MIB on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, logging, cisco, snmp, mib

I am trying to decode the SNMP traps in plain text, and need some help on how to install the Cisco MIB in Ubuntu so I can parse these logs.

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.5 LTS

E.g.:

2023-04-24 18:18:55  [UDP: [10.10.0.15]:49924->[10.10.1.24]:162]:
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (1386292) 3:51:02.92   iso.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4    iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.7 = INTEGER: 7    iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.7 = INTEGER: 1    iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.7 = INTEGER: 1    iso.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.2483

Please help.

Comment: There is no info that can be used to help you in this question. What is Cisco MIB? What command did you use to install it? What errors did you get?

Comment: Your provided details highlight you've not fully upgraded your system, thus for starters I'd suggest you apply all security fixes asap (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded to it before that date).